# Add string to email subject IF not already there

Tags: vba, outlook

I tried the code below and get a Compile error: invalid qualifier on olMail. 
I attached a pic of the error. Ok so it says I need to add more details of the problem so in detail, I want to add a string to the beginning of a subject line in outlook if that string is not already present. If the string is already present, I don't want to change it:

```
Sub Addstring()
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
Dim aItem As Object

Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mail = myolApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Dim iItemsUpdated As Integer
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strFilenum As String

strname = InputBox("Enter the string to add to subject i.e John ")
iItemsUpdated = 0
For Each aItem In mail.Items
   If Left(LCase(olMail.Subject), 10) <> "(strname)" Then
    ' edit the subject
     strTemp = "[" & strFilenum & "] " & aItem.Subject
      aItem.Subject = strTemp
      iItemsUpdated = iItemsUpdated + 1
    aItem.Save
End If
Next aItem

MsgBox iItemsUpdated & " of " & mail.Items.Count & " Messages Updated"
Set myolApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Error:

[image: error]

Answer (score -1):

You need to correct the name of variable. It is declared as `aItem` but later you try to use `olMail` object which is not defined anywhere.

```
Sub Addstring()
  Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim aItem As Object

  Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set mail = myolApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

  Dim iItemsUpdated As Integer
  Dim strTemp As String
  Dim strFilenum As String

  strname = InputBox("Enter the string to add to subject i.e John ")
  iItemsUpdated = 0
  For Each aItem In mail.Items
    If Left(LCase(aItem.Subject), 10) <> "(strname)" Then
      ' edit the subject
      strTemp = "[" & strFilenum & "] " & aItem.Subject
      aItem.Subject = strTemp
      iItemsUpdated = iItemsUpdated + 1
      aItem.Save
    End If
  Next aItem

  MsgBox iItemsUpdated & " of " & mail.Items.Count & " Messages Updated"
  Set myolApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! My next issue is that the "if" test doesnt seem to test properly. if (Thisword) is already at the beginning of the subject i.e.. (Thisword) This is a test subject
the subject becomes (Thisword) (Thisword) This is a test subject.

I tried escaping ( with no change.I tried changing ( to [ in case parens were the  issue, same result.  
I'm thinking of just checking for ( as the first character. 
When I added Dim firstChar = str.First() before the if it was red, and within the for loop these were red
 Dim firstChar = str.First()
 If firstChar <> ( Then

Comment: That is another question. I'd suggest asking separate questions in another threads so readers could recognize questions and answers easily. In the meantime you may find the [The Ultimate Guide to VBA String Functions](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-string-functions/) and [VBA String Functions – A Primer](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-string-functions/) pages helpful.